# Doctrine2 Define properties via magic methods

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine, is it possible to map to properties which don't actually exist using magic methods?

I'm doing the mapping with YAML.

For example, if I wanted to map to a property named "demo", but SomeClass::$demo didn't actually exist. I'd want to some combination of __get(), __set(), __isset() and __call() to handle $demo (and getDemo() and setDemo()) and do something else with them.

I've tried setting this up, but I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Property My\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\SomeClass::$demo does not exist'
```

I'm not sure if there is something special with the ReflectionProperty that causes it to miss my magic methods, or if I'm maybe missing a magic function. However, as far as I can tell, ReflectionProperty should interact with them.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Upon further investigation, it looks like the ReflectionProperty constructor will throw an exception and won't trigger the magic methods.

Does anyone else know of means to map Doctrine to dynamic properties?

Thanks.

UPDATE 2:

To example what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically, I have a generic `User` object which just contains the base properties needed to handle actually being a user (roles, password, salt, username, etc.). However, I want to be able to extend this object to add application-and-user-specific meta data.

So, say I create a Forum bundle. I could then I could dynamically hook up meta data related to the user for use with the Forum. I don't want to put it directly in the User bundle, because then the User bundle becomes less flexible.

If I could somehow dynamically inject new data in to the user, it could all be loaded in a single query with the user, instead of having to be loaded in a separate query. I know there are some other methods to do this, which I've already explored and even used to a limited extend. However, it'd be much nicer if I could dynamically create these associations, which really shouldn't be that difficult of a leap.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Updated my question with more details.

Comment: I can't image how the data layer is meant to handle this. Why not just create some extra *one-to-many* associations?

Comment: That's basically what I'm trying to do. However, to create those one-to-many associations, I still have to have a property to map it to. The thing is, I don't want the properties themselves to be explicitly defined as members of the User object. I want them to be dynamically defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to search on these dynamic properties then just add a property called data to your entity and map it to a doctrine array type.  Now do your majic stuff and store the dynamic properties in the data array.

A second approach might be along these lines:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html.  For each installation you might be able to give the administrators of making a custom entity.

But as long as you don't need to directly query on your dynamic properties then the first method works well.

Comment: If I'm understanding your first approach, I don't think that will work. Well, it will, but it's already what I do. It ends up requiring additional queries. My goal is to get the object to load those extra relations all in one (left-joined) query. I'll take a look at that link you provided though, I haven't come across that article yet.

Comment: Nope.  I guess I was not clear.  You add one column to your user table with type array.  You can store whatever additional application specific data you want in it.  Whenever you query your user entity, the data array will be loaded.  No need for joins or any additional queries.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that could certainly work, but it's not an approach I would really want to use. I like using well defined objects for everything.